# Body('email') email:string / Body() email:string : what's the difference?

Tags: nestjs

I am using nestjs.

here's auth 'service' code. "email" and 'vericode" parameters are both string.

```
  async emailSender(email: string) {
    const vericode = this.generateOTP();
    await this.cacheManager.set(email, vericode);
    await this.emailService.sendMail({
      to: email,
      subject: `verification code`,
      text: `verification code is ${vericode}`,
    });
    return 'success';
  }
```

here's auth controller's code

```
  @Post('/email/send')
  async emailSend(@Body() email: string) {
    return this.authService.emailSender(email);
  }
```

if I change Body() to Body('email') as blow then the error below as "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] node_redis: The SETEX command contains a invalid argument type.
Only strings, dates and buffers are accepted. Please update your code to use valid argument types.Error: node_redis: The SETEX command contains a invalid argument type." disappears. why's that?

```
  @Post('/email/send')
  async emailSend(@Body('email') email: string) {
    return this.authService.emailSender(email);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Body() email: string` is incorrect, as `@Body()` on its own brings into the handler `req.body`. That means that the type should at least be `Record<string, unknown>` or a Class based DTO that can be validated against.

`@Body('email') email: string` is correct as it brings in `req.body['email']`, so as long as there's an `email` property in the body, Nest will pass it to the controller.